# PHP socket - wrong result length - additional characters

Tags: php, string, sockets

I am using the following function:

```
function createSocket($host, $script, $request, $method="POST", $port="8080") {
    $request_length = strlen($request);
    $output="";
    $script .= "?$request";
    //echo  "host=".Middle_Tier;

    $header = "$method $script HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $header .= "Host: $host\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: $request_length\r\n";
    $header .= "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "$request\r\n";

    $socket = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr);

    if ($socket) //if its open, then...
    {
    fputs($socket, $header); // send the details over
    while(!feof($socket)) {
        $output[] = fgets($socket); //get the results
    }
    return $output;
    fclose($socket);
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
}

$host    = 'my host';
$script  = 'path/to/my/function';
$request = "phone=$phone&city_id=$city_id";

$arr = createSocket($host, $script, $request, $method="POST", $port="8080");
```

I get this result from my destination:

```
$arr[9] = unavailable
```

and when I print:

```
strlen($arr[9]);
```

the output is **14** (i.e 3 additional character)

Comment: please show the output of print_r( $arr )

Comment: use `var_dump` to see the actual contents of a variable. `var_dump` also outputs the length. don't use print_r, ever. for example `var_dump("unavailable  ")` prints out `string 'unavailable  ' (length=13)`. `print_r("unavailable  ");` just outputs the string and the two spaces, without giving any further information.

Comment: By using var_dump I get:

 [9] => string(5) "unavailable"

why when I print $arr[9] the out put is only:
 unavailable    
????

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your code.

1. you're using `HTTP/1.1` without handling [chunked encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) If you don't need/want any of the fancy HTTP 1.1 features, use HTTP/1.0 instead.
2. you're expecting a certain information to be sent in the 9th line of the response. What if the order of HTTP response headers changes (say because another header was introduced)? You don't account for this. Result: your code may break at any given time.
3. Why not use [curl](http://php.net/curl) for the "heavy lifting"?

Comment: By using var_dump I get:
[9] => string(5) "unavailable"
why when I print $arr[9] the out put is only: unavailable ???? 
How I make my conditions??